# Total number of TP, TN, FP & FN do not sum up to total number of observed values

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, metrics, confusion-matrix

I was going through the [Classification on imbalanced data](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/imbalanced_data) by TensorFlow. Here in this tutorial they have used [Kaggle's Credit Card Fraud Detection](https://www.kaggle.com/mlg-ulb/creditcardfraud). In [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/imbalanced_data#clean_split_and_normalize_the_data) section you could see that the number of **training** examples are **182276** and number of **validation** samples are **45569**. To evaluate the baseline model they have used Keras's inbuilt metrics - TruePositive, FalsePositive, TrueNegative, FalseNegative.

However if you look at the training logs in [train the model](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/imbalanced_data#train_the_model) section then you can see that the sum of FP+TP+FN+TN is not equal to number of training examples. Nor the sum is equal to number of validation examples for validation data.

### Part 1

**EPOCH 1**

```
TP = 64
FP = 25
TN = 139431.9780
FN = 188.3956
TP+FP+TN+FN = 139709.3736
```

The above sum is nowhere close to 182276. Same is true for all the subsequent epochs. Why is this the case?

### Part 2

As the number of epoch increases, the total sum decreases further. For example compare the values for epoch 2 and 1.
**EPOCH 2**

```
TP - 25
FP - 5.67
TN - 93973.1538
FN - 136.2967 
TP+FP+TN+FN = 94135.1205
```

The total sum is now reduced further by 45574. Same is true for epochs lower down the order.

1. Shouldn't the total sum be the same?
2. If not then why does it keep on decreasing?

### Part 3

Why are the values for TP, FP, FN, TN in both training and validation floating numbers? As per my understanding these should always be integer. As per the explanation in the [Understanding useful metrics](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/imbalanced_data#understanding_useful_metrics) the values represent count and should hence be integers.

Comment: That's strange indeed they need to be integers. So I downloaded the data myself and tested it. All values were integers. There might be something wrong with dataset processing. Also you can check this [link](https://keras.io/examples/structured_data/imbalanced_classification/)

Comment: Did you try on multiple runs? Was it still the same? Any ideas about the other questions?

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing a similar issue for me the sum of TP, TN, FP, and FN doubled each epoch and were non integers. my solution was that my model was built using tensor flows keras but I imported keras directly.

so instead of

```
import keras
```

use

```
from tensorflow import keras
```